# Episode VII -- Deleted Scene

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, deleted-scenes

A few days ago, the 3D Collector's edition for *The Force Awakens* was released. It included the deleted scene with Leia and Korr Sella which was present in the film novelization. I really want more context on the conversation between the two of them during the scene. If anyone has seen the clip, could you please describe the dialogue spoken during the moment and where the scene takes place?

Comment: Interestingly, these scenes don't appear in the [released screenplay](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Force-Awakens.html), only the novelisation, suggesting that they were in an earlier draft script and were removed *before filming started*. Since they clearly do exist, the cynic in me thinks that they were filmed ***specifically for inclusion as "deleted" scenes***.

Answer (score 2):

This scene occurs earlier in the film, just after Han escaped in the Falcon and the Guavian Trader contacted the First Order. There were actually two deleted scenes, one where Leia gets the message that the village on Jakku has been eliminated and a second one where she briefs Korr Sella on the situation.

> *In another room, Korr Sella, Leia’s personal envoy, awaited the
>   general’s arrival. The young woman wore her hair back in a severe bun
>   and her dark green uniform contrasted notably with the general’s more
>   subdued attire, as did the badge that identified her as a commander.
>   As usual, Leia did not waste time on small talk.*
>
> *“You need to go to the Senate right away. Tell them I insist that they
>   take action against the First Order. The longer they bicker and delay,
>   the stronger the Order becomes.” She leaned toward the other woman.
>   “If they fail to take action soon, the Order will have grown so strong
>   the Senate will be unable to do anything. It won’t matter what they
>   think.”*
>
> *Sella indicated her understanding. “With all respect: Do you think the
>   senators will listen?”*
>
> *“I don’t know.” Leia bit down on her lower lip. “So much time has
>   passed. There was a time when they were at least willing to listen.
>   And of course, the Senate’s makeup has changed. Some of those who were
>   always willing to pay attention to me have retired. Some of those who
>   have replaced them have their own agendas.” She smiled ruefully. “Not
>   all senators think I’m crazy. Or maybe they do. I don’t care what they
>   think about me as long as they take action.” The emissary nodded.
>   “I’ll do all I can to ensure the Resistance gets the hearing we
>   deserve. But why don’t you go yourself, General? An appeal of this
>   nature is always more effective when delivered firsthand.”*
>
> *Leia’s smile thinned. “I might make it to the Senate, yes. I might
>   even be able to deliver my speech. But I would never, never get out of
>   the Hosnian system alive. I would have a terrible ‘accident,’ or
>   become the victim of some ‘deranged’ radical. Or I would eat something
>   that didn’t agree with me. Or encounter someone who didn’t agree with
>   me.” She composed herself. “I have total confidence in you, Sella. I
>   know you will deliver our message to the full extent of your
>   considerable abilities.”*
>
> *The emissary smiled back, grateful for the confidence the general was
>   expressing.*

As to *why* these scenes were removed, the answer is that they really add nothing in terms of plotting. We already know that the Village has been destroyed (since we saw it happen) and we don't really care what's going on in the Senate since their involvement in the rest of the film is nil, aside from making a nice fat target for the First Order.

Comment: If you can, could you please post an image of the scene?

Comment: @JonathanLopez - I've not got that set yet and I'm struggling to find a screencap online.